# How to redirect to an absolute url path in django?

Tags: django, url, redirect, django-templates

I am trying to reroute to the "listing" path from the the watchlist page using the 'url' attribute in Django templates. However, the problem is that Django ignores the parts of the URL it has already used in rerouting (i.e."/watchlist") and so looks for the url with path "/watchlist/listing_title" instead of just "/listing_title", which is what I want. Is there a way to work around this?

urls.py

```
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("<str:listing_title>", views.listing, name="listing"),
path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
```

watchlist.html

```
<a href={% url 'listing' listing.title %}">
```

Comment: It will nevver access `watchlist`, since the `<str:listing_title>` will match for `/watchlist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never access `watchlist`, since the `<str:listing_title>` will match for `/watchlist`. You should reorder the paths, and work with:

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('watchlist', views.watchlist, name='watchlist'),
path('<str:listing_title>', views.listing, name='listing'),
```

Django will enumerate over all the URL patterns top-to-bottom, and "fire" the first view that has a matching URL pattern. If we thus put `<str:listing_title>` first, it will match `watchlist` with that `<str:…>` path part, and thus never trigger the `listing`.